# errors in android studio that I can't solve at all

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, sdk

I have this errors in android studio and I have tried many ways to solve this but it's not working at all.

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find savedstate-1.1.0.aar (androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/savedstate/savedstate/1.1.0/savedstate-1.1.0.aar
> Could not find lifecycle-runtime-2.3.1.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.3.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-runtime/2.3.1/lifecycle-runtime-2.3.1.aar
> Could not find lifecycle-viewmodel-2.3.1.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.3.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-viewmodel/2.3.1/lifecycle-viewmodel-2.3.1.aar
> Could not find lifecycle-livedata-core-2.3.1.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.3.1).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-livedata-core/2.3.1/lifecycle-livedata-core-2.3.1.aar

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZNkb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp9nv.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WajQq.png)

this pictures may help you more

could you guys help me please? thanks!

Comment: Might be better to indicate what you have tried instead of juts "many ways."

Comment: can you share screenshot of gradle file

Comment: post your dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Based on the images you have provided, it seems like you have not implemented those dependencies:

Try add this to your `build.gradle (app)` :

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.1.0'
```

Comment: sorry but it didn't work. I still have the same errors